# Command Line CD (Change Directory) variant in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

I want to write a simple C# console application to change the current directory of the command line to a directory the application works out.  Looking through MSDN [System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory.aspx) looks ideal for this until I saw in the remarks that:

> 'When the application terminates, the
>   working directory is restored to its
>   original location (the directory where
>   the process was started).'

And sure enough when I tried this in a test application it didn't work.  Does anyone have any idea how to implement a CD variant in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a wrapper batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('someapp.exe') do SET TOOLOUTPUT=%%i 
CD %TOOLOUTPUT%
```

I haven't tested this, but it should get you where you are trying to go.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that is possible, as you are just setting the current working directory for your program instead of the cmd process that spawned it.